# Issue with gdal warp

Tags: gdal

I'm trying to clip a raster with a polygon layer containing multiple features. To achieve my goal I'm trying to execute those commands lines on a batch file :

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin
gdalwarp   -cutline C:\poly1.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -cwhere "'id' = 
'1'"   -r bilinear    C:\western_1.tif  C:\1_dma_western.tif
gdalwarp   -cutline C:\poly1.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -cwhere "'id' = 
'2'"    -r bilinear   C:\western_1.tif  C:\2_dma_western.tif
gdalwarp   -cutline C:\poly1.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -cwhere "'id' = 
'3'"   -r bilinear    C:\western_1.tif  C:\3_dma_western.tif
pause
```

unfortunately I get this Error :

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the 
GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv 
files.
ERROR 1: Did not get any cutline features.
```

Both, raster and  polygon layer are using the same EPSG. 
I'm working with gdal which is  installed with qgis. 
Your help would be warmly appreciated. 
Cordially.

Comment: The error states you need to set the GDAL_DATA env. variable. Did you do that?
I think it needs to point to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\share\gdal\`

Comment: solved https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259009/error-4-unable-to-open-epsg-support-file-with-gdal-warp/259122#259122 thank you.